# Anyone know how to utilize Wordpress Plugin(Event Manager)? I need convert default event manager listview into another viewing type

Tags: php, events, wordpress, modification-form

Event manager provided services to the user to list out the event that been created in the back-end,and display it anywhere as long as the [shorcode](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/shortcodes/) is keyed.

For now problem here is, i would like to modify the way it display, for now it display list view and no matter how hard i try, it couldn't change to what i want.

How i do the modification is that i go to the Event Manager > setting > Formatting > Event.
And i just key in some [placeholder](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/placeholders/) that provided by event manager together with the table format that i done to list it out.

[image]

Code in the backend:-

```
 <table>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>#_EVENTDATES</td>
        <td>#_EVENTIMAGE{133,200}</td>
        <td>#_EVENTNOTES</td>
        <td>#_#_EVENTID</td>
        <td>#_#_EVENTIMAGEURL</td>
        <td>#_EVENTNAME</td>
        <td>Note: <a class="more-link" href="http://dummy.com/">Continue reading <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Below is the current layout

[image]

But what i want it to looks like is something like this.

[image]

In addition, for my opinion, i feel that it probably need to modify not only on the wordpress backend, but also the file behind, but im not sure which one should i modify, as i just started PHP. Can anyone help on this please. :)

Below is the file path and file name.

[image]

[image]

You can find the file from event manager [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/).

Comment: You should be able to do that with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be a file `plugins->events manager->templates->templates->events-list.php` with code as below,

```
$args = apply_filters('em_content_events_args', $args);

if( get_option('dbem_css_evlist') ) echo "<div class='css-events-list'>";

echo EM_Events::output( $args );

if( get_option('dbem_css_evlist') ) echo "</div>";
```

Copy these codes to a new page where you want to display the events make changes to it. For example

```
echo EM_Events::output(array('format'=>
'<a href="#_EVENTURL" border=0></a>
<B>#_EVENTLINK</B><br/>#_EVENTDATES #_EVENTTIMES<BR/>
<i>#_LOCATIONNAME, #_LOCATIONADDRESS, #_LOCATIONTOWN</i>
<br/><a href="#_EVENTURL">Details & map</a><HR>',
'limit'=>20, 'pagination'=>1));
```